# Is there a way to get the engine from the SQLAlchemy object?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following code:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(
    engine_options={ 'connect_args': { 'connect_timeout': 60 }}
)

basis_engine = create_engine(database_stages["dev"]["dev_basis"])
meta_data = MetaData()
meta_data.reflect(bind=basis_engine)
```

I've created the engine just to be able to access directly a single table, and that adds a great amount of overhead to the app when I start it up (It takes much more time). So, is there a way to get the engine from the `SQLAlchemy` object and avoid `create_engine`?

Comment: Umm, `create_engine` *is* how you get an Engine object from SQLAlchemy. Are you asking how to get a DBAPI *connection* without calling `create_engine`?

Comment: I want to be able to call MetaData().reflect without calling create_engine, because I already access that database from SQLAlchemy, so it's a bit redundant to call create_engine.

Comment: It looks like you want to derive the engine from an flask-sqlalchemy object, is that right?

Comment: If you "already access that database from SQLAlchemy" then presumably you already have an engine object somewhere. BTW if this is a Flask question please tag it as such.

Comment: Yes, it is a flask-sqlalchemy object, I've added the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `db` object (an instance of `SQLAlchemy`) has a [get_engine](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/?highlight=get_engine#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.get_engine) method that will return an engine.